# clang-format: Setting to control C++ attributes

Tags: clang-format

Searching through the [Clang-Format Style Options](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html), I can't seem to find a way to control the behavior on the placement of C++ attributes.

As an example, take these two declarations, the first of which does not overflow the column limit and the second of which does:

```
template <typename TChar>
[[gnu::always_inline]]
static ptr<TChar> within_limit(ptr<TChar> first, ptr<TChar> last);

template <typename TChar, typename FApply, typename... FApplyRest>
[[gnu::always_inline]]
static ptr<TChar> overflow(ptr<TChar> first, ptr<TChar> last, const FApply& apply, const FApplyRest&... apply_rest);
```

No matter how I tweak my `.clang-format`, the output is some variant of this:

```
[[gnu::always_inline]] static ptr<TChar> within_limit(ptr<TChar> first, ptr<TChar> last);

[[gnu::always_inline]] static ptr<TChar>
overflow(ptr<TChar> first, ptr<TChar> last, const FApply& apply, const FApplyRest&... apply_rest);
```

Having the attributes on the same line as the type is rather unreadable (to me), so I would prefer `clang-format` not do this. Using `__attribute__((always_inline))` exhibits the same behavior. Specifying multiple attributes in a single list (`[[noreturn, gnu::cold]]`) causes reformatting (to `[[ noreturn, gnu::cold ]]` for reasons unclear to me). The formatter has at least some basic understanding of attributes.

**SO:** Is there a way to get `clang-format` to put attributes on their own line (the C++ equivalent to `BreakAfterJavaFieldAnnotations`)?

---

**Attempted Workarounds**

Use of `// clang-format off`/`// clang-format on` is an *okay* stopgap, but it is definitely too ham-handed for a permanent solution. I still want the declaration formatted properly. Aside from that, the project requires the use of a lot of attributes, so having `clang-format` comments everywhere is arguably less readable.

Use of `CommentPragmas` theoretically would allow me to be more localized in disabling, but the output is still quite odd:

```
template <typename TChar>
[[gnu::always_inline]] // NO-FORMAT: Attribute
    static ptr<TChar>
    within_limit(ptr<TChar> first, ptr<TChar> last);
```

Comment: I'm looking for a solution to this same issue for [[deprecated]] attribute specifiers. From what I can tell, this is possibly a missing feature of clang-format. Have you found a solution?

Comment: It has not been added as of Clang 6 -- https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html.

Comment: Similar issue for the `[[nodiscard]]` attribute specifier. Any workarounds using other clang-format properties?

Comment: As of Clang 10, it does not exist.

Comment: I'm having this problem and clang-format off doesn't even work.

Comment: Did you consider logging this over in http://bugs.llvm.org

Comment: You should set the Standard of your clang-format style to c++17, earlier standard formatting does not comply with the syntax changes. If using an existing preset you might want to make a copy of it with `clang-format --style=(LLVM, WebKit, etc.) --dump-config` and override.

Comment: Looking for the same. As of Clang 11, it still does not exist :(

Comment: It seems this still does not exist in `clang-format` v12.0.0?! I really want to use `[[nodiscard]]`, but this missing feature "destroys" our nicely aligned functions using trailing return types: `[[nodiscard]] auto f() -> void;`

Comment: v13.0.0: nope. Very sad.

Comment: v16: Fixed with `BreakAfterAttributes`: https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html#breakafterattributes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The feature you're asking for has been added in clang-format 16. The attribute is called `BreakAfterAttributes` [(documentation)](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html#breakafterattributes), and for the behavior you asked for (newlines after the attribute group) is `Always`.

Section for this attribute from the [docs](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html#breakafterattributes):

> #### BreakAfterAttributes
>
> Break after a group of C++11 attributes before a function declaration/definition name.
>
> Possible values:
>
> - `ABS_Always` (in configuration: `Always`) Always break after attributes.
>
> ```cpp
> [[nodiscard]]
> inline int f();
> [[gnu::const]] [[nodiscard]]
> int g();
> ```
>
> - `ABS_Leave` (in configuration: `Leave`) Leave the line breaking after attributes as is.
>
> ```cpp
> [[nodiscard]] inline int f();
> [[gnu::const]] [[nodiscard]]
> int g();
> ```
>
> - `ABS_Never` (in configuration: `Never`) Never break after attributes.
>
> ```cpp
> [[nodiscard]] inline int f();
> [[gnu::const]] [[nodiscard]] int g();
> ```

There does not seem to be a setting for breaking after *each* attribute in the group, as of clang-format 17. If anyone coming here is interested in that.
e.g.:

```cpp
// Even `Leave` will format this into one line
[[gnu::const]]
[[nodiscard]]
int g();
```

The line comment trick suggested by [Possseidon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6924740/possseidon) in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69090680/12848953) will work for this.

```cpp
// Will remain like this when using `Leave` or `Always`
[[gnu::const]] // <-- Empty line comment after each attribute you want a break after
[[nodiscard]]
int g();
```

Answer (score 3):

This is not a "solution", but a general workaround for preventing clang-format (and other formatters) from removing line breaks.

Just add an empty line comment at the end of a line like so:

```cpp
template <typename TChar>
[[gnu::always_inline]] //
static ptr<TChar>
within_limit(ptr<TChar> first, ptr<TChar> last);

template <typename TChar, typename FApply, typename... FApplyRest>
[[gnu::always_inline]] //
static ptr<TChar>
overflow(ptr<TChar> first, ptr<TChar> last, const FApply& apply, const FApplyRest&... apply_rest);
```

It can't merge the lines now, as this would comment out the entire rest of the line.

For this specific example, it's unfortunately not perfect, as it also seems to introduce a second line break after the return type (which looks arguably worse than having everything on a single line). Nontheless I thought this might come in handy in some scenarios (although I haven't personally used it all that much either).

It's at least a lot less verbose than turning off clang-format completely for just a single line.

Comment: Could you share what you tweaked in your clang-format to keep it in this way? My clang-format add weird stuff...

Comment: Try comparing it to [this](https://github.com/Possseidon/dang-lib/blob/master/.clang-format) one. That's the one I'm generally using.